# Unable to display values in the table in angular

Tags: angular, angular5

getting error as
 **TypeError: Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined
    at** 
line number mat table

code is in material angular

```
 import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import { User } from '../some';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})


 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    public Visits: any;

   public constructor(private location: Location, private http: Http, private router: Router){
      this.Visits = [];
       }

   public ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/visit')
    .map(result =>  ['result'])
    .subscribe(result => {
        this.Visits = result ;
        console.log('submit get click happend ' + this.Visits );
    return this.Visits;

    });

  }
      create= function () {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);

        }

      }
```

To display values in the table i am using the below code 
 table is build from angular material

```
<mat-table #table>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="height">
    <mat-header-cell> ID </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit of Visits"> {{visit.height}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <mat-header-cell> Progress </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit"> {{visit.weight}}% </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="patientnote">
    <mat-header-cell > Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit"> {{visit.patientnote}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="doctornote">
    <mat-header-cell > Color </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *ngFor="let visit"> {{visit.doctornote}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

</mat-table>
```

and interface

```
export interface User {
    username: string;
    height: string;
    weight: string;
    Temperature: string;
    bloodpressure: string;
    patientnote: string;
    nursenote: string;
    doctornote: string;

    }
```

could you please help me to fix this issue

updated the code which is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Your service is not getting called, you need to place it inside **`ngOnInit`**

```
public constructor(private location: Location, private http: Http, private router: Router){
      this.Visits = [];
}
ngOnInit(): void {
         this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/visit')
           .map(result => result.json())
           .subscribe(result => {
            this.Visits = result;
          });
}
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan,
i am using ngOnInit and updating complete code in the post above

Comment: what is this.location.subscribe?

Comment: actually my service from golang and followed this one

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/02/build-a-full-stack-movie-database-with-golang-angular-and-nosql/

Comment: it does not matter golang or whatever service, you dont need subscribe there. just call the method

Comment: added a image in post what iam getting in response from my service.

Comment: removed this.location.subscribe and with ngOnInit also i tried getting same response as  Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 129
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: dont do json.stringify. because your result is already a json.  this.Visits =   result;

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, after remove json.stringfy code works fine but for displaying  vales in the table getting error. added a screenshot of error in post what i am getting .

Comment: this.Visits =  ['result']; added in my code errors fixed but not displaying values in table

Comment: i have updated the post with latest code changes but still unable to display values in the table by using **ngFor** .

Answer (score 0):

your typescript file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  users = [];
  form: any;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'first_name': new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(2)),
      'last_name': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })

    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.httpClient.get('https://reqres.in/api/users').subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.users = response.data;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  saveUser() {
    this.httpClient.post('https://reqres.in/api/users', this.form.value).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.users.unshift(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

your html file

Start editing to see some magic happen :)

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="saveUser()">
      <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="name">
      <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="lname">
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<div *ngFor="let user of users">
    <h1>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</h1>
    <img [src]="user.avatar"/>
</div>
```